# How to Assign Value to Array in List Object in C#

Tags: asp.net

I have a `List<Semesters>` Object and `Semesters` class has `Semester` as `String[]` type. Below is my code which has error where `Semester[1]= item.Semester`. What is the correct syntax?

```
 public class CourseList
    {
        public int? Prog_id { get; set; }
        public List<Semesters> Series{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Semesters
    {

        public string[] Semester { get; set; }   
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public int Credit {get; set;}

    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public CourseList GetCourseList(int Progid)
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            CourseList Obj = new CourseList();
              List<Semesters> CObj = new List<Semesters>();


            var qry = (from a in context.Courses
                       where a.Prog_id == Progid             
                       orderby a.Semester
                       select a).ToList();

            foreach (var item in qry)
            {
                Obj.Prog_id = item.Prog_id;


                if (item.Semester.ToString() == "1st Semester")
                { 
                    CObj.Add(new Semesters {Semester[1]=item.Semester, Subject = item.Subject.ToString(), Coursetitle= item.Coursetitle });

                }
                if (item.Semester.ToString() == "2nd Semester")
                {
                    CObj.Add(new Semesters { Semester[2] = item.Semester, Subject = item.Subject.ToString(), Coursetitle = item.Coursetitle });

                }


                Obj.Series = CObj;
            }

            return Obj;
        }
```

Comment: what is `qry` in this code?

Comment: qry is a linq query which return list of data.

Comment: both Semester[1]= item.Semester and Semester=item.Semester have red line underneath it. Cannot implicitly to convert string to string[]

Comment: Ok. why is `public string[] Semester { get; set; }` an array, and not just a single string? In your code you never try to allocate more than one value into the array, so it's not clear why you would need one. Since it's part of an object called "Semesters", doesn't mean that this object represents one semester for a particular course? Your data structure is a little unclear, but it seems like really your object should match the (relevant parts of) the structure of the Courses db table?

Comment: If you can confirm what structure you're actually trying to show, I can help you by writing a proper answer. Should it be that each "Semesters" object represents a course taking place in one specific semester (which appears to be the structure in the database), or does it somehow represent a course, with an attached list of _all_ the semesters in which that course is scheduled (which is what the class currently appears to do)? There's a mismatch between the database's structure and your class's structure which needs explaining.

Comment: If the former is your intention, then you can simply turn your string array into a single string. If the latter is your intention, then you perhaps need to write a different SQL query, or process the query results differently. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You say `Semester` is an array of strings, so in this statement

```
Semester[1] = item.Semester
```

`Semester` is an array and `item.Semester` is an array.

`Semester[1]` should be assigned a string, but you are assigning it an array. You'll need to change it to (possibly...)

```
// assign a value from the item.Semester array.
Semester[1] = item.Semester[n]
```

That's one possibility w/o more info.

Comment: I posted my updated code above to better explain my purpose. I am trying to group semesters into Semester array.